# is there any good library for printing preview in MFC?

Tags: c++, mfc, print-preview

I need to print records in a grid view, and need to preview it before 
printing. 
I want to know whether or not there is a strong library for printing 
preview? 
And with the library I can change the position, layout of the data to 
print.

**More important: I need to change the data's layout, how can I do that?**

Comment: note that whatever print preview code you'll find, you'll have to write extra code to adjust it to your needs. Personally I don't like MFC print preview, anyway check this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031036/implementing-my-own-print-preview and also search http://www.codeproject.com for print preview code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MFC itself supports [Print Preview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/edak6tf8(VS.80).aspx), there shouldn't be a need for an additional library.

Comment: is this library can change it's layout ?

Comment: sorry but MFC print preview sucks.

Comment: any better solution ? let's say i want to print a bill according the records in database, how can i do it ?